# Find all quotes in json-like string and replace quotes inside using Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string which has similar structure to `JSON` like this:

```
"data1":{

    "data2":{
        "x":"Some text"
    },
    "source": "source: <a href=\"http://example.com/content/123/data123.pdf\">example.com</a>" }
    "data3":{
        "format": "f() { return this.data52 / 20 + "x"; }"
}
```

I want to remove quotes inside quotes like this:

```
"data1":{

    "data2":{
        "x":"Some text"
    },
    "source": "source: <a href=\"http://example.com/content/123/data123.pdf\">example.com</a>" }
    "data3":{
        "format": "f() { return this.data52 / 20 + \"x\"; }"
}
```

The string given in input is much longer, and I have many strings like this to format. As you can see some of the quotes are changed to `\"` already. I tried this:

`string = re.sub(r"\"(.*)\"",  r"\1", string).re.replace("\"", "\\\"")`

but it replaces all quotes, I tried to use negative lookaround but it would work only if I have only one quote and another inside. Is there ANY way to do that with regex? I could always iterate over string and count the quotes but it is not the best solution I suppose. Thanks for help!

**@EDIT**

I founded where the algorithm provided by @L3viathan doesn't work:

```
"data1":{

    "data2":{
        "x":"Some text"
    },
    "source": "source: <a href=\"http://example.com/content/123/data123.pdf\">example.com</a>" }
    "data3":{
        "hereDoesntWork": {
            "format": "f() { return this.data52 / 20 + "x"; }"
         }
     }
}
```

The text in "hereDoesntWork` is just ommited. The thing is that I don't know how this strings can be nested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't managed to do it with a single regex, but two should do it:

```
import re

pattern = '"(.*?)"(.*?)"(.*)"'

s = """"data1":{

    "data2":{
        "x":"Some text"
    },
    "source": "source: <a href=\"http://example.com/content/123/data123.pdf\">example.com</a>" }
    "data3":{
        "format": "f() { return this.data52 / 20 + "x"; }"
}"""

def fixer(match):
    key = match.group(1)
    middle = match.group(2)
    content = match.group(3)
    print(key, middle, content)
    return '"{}"{}"{}"'.format(
            key,
            middle,
            re.sub(r'(?<!\\)"', r'\"', content),
    )

print(re.sub(pattern, fixer, s))
```

First, I call `re.sub` with a function as the replacement argument, which causes it to call it with the match for every match that it finds, and replace it with the return value of that function.

The first regex (`pattern`) just matches lines with four or more quotes, matching the part between the last two greedily. The second regex (in `fixer`) matches quote characters that are not preceeded by a backslash.

Comment: Sounds great but in practice it changes only the first quotes in `data1` (where it shouldn't be changed)

Comment: What do you mean? For me it changes only the quotes around the `x` in the second to last line. `diff` tells me the results are identical to your second code block.

Comment: that is probably my actual string is much compicated... Do you know what to change if my string will be in one line?

Comment: If your actual string is in one line, then why don't you have it that way in your question?

Comment: Im doing some format before this one, that is why, I will try to put this before deleting the new lines

Comment: this matches only if I have got " text "dsda" text2" what if I have more quotes inside?

Comment: It works with an arbitrary number of quotes inside the value string.

Comment: I found where in what cases it doesn't work. The question is edited. Can check this out?

Comment: @soommy12 I can't confirm, it works flawlessly on my computer. That said, there _are_ of course cases where this wouldn't work, but some of them are unfixable.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I solved my problem in the other way but your solution helped me a lot, thanks!